# Multiple line to single line in php

Tags: php, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all the line breaks from the html source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258543/remove-all-the-line-breaks-from-the-html-source)

I have a code bellow

```
$a = "<br />
      <br />Regards<br />
      admin";
```

the out put is same as above code and, i want the result following format

```
<br /><br />Regards<br />admin
```

Comment: `$b = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $a);`

Comment: That might not work as line breaks might differ in script and local machine.

Answer (score 0):

this is about [string replace](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
    $a = "<br />
          <br />Regards<br />
          admin";

    $a = str_replace(PHP_EOL,"",$a);

    var_dump($a);

// Regexp example

$a = preg_replace('/$/','',$a);
```

Comment: That might not work as line breaks might differ in script and local machine.

Comment: PHP_EOL is the correct 'End Of Line' symbol for the platform which is your php running on.

Comment: True, but a doc might have other symbols.

Comment: Delete ALL the newlines!  `preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '', $foo)`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
print_r($a);
```

i guess this should do the trick

Comment: [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) is a debugging tool, not a way to produce output intended for users.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just about prettifying your code, can you just use this?

```
$a = "<br />".
     "<br />Regards<br />".
     "admin";
```

I've done that on many occasions.  Otherwise, as mentioned by Tufan above, you'll have to do some parsing and replacing of your text.