# How to remove all line breaks OUTSIDE of html tags

Tags: php, html, string

I'm cleaning some html files by php script and I want to remove all the `\n` thingies that are not between a `<tag></tag>`.

```
<p>some text</p>


           <- here are the bunch of \n I want to remove


<p>some other random
text with \n at fixed width
and that's great</p>
```

Any ideas ?
Many thanks.

Comment: You mean inside the `<body>` tag but outside any of its child tags.

Comment: Outside of any <tag> in the html code. <tag>good</tag>notgood<tag>good</tag>

Comment: Use a DOM parser for that, and remove all child tags that are just whitespace. Have you already looked at the documentation of `DOMDocument`?

Comment: You don't have any `<html>` tag in your HTML? How is that so?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258543/remove-all-the-line-breaks-from-the-html-source

Comment: @Jacob not quite. Any text-based approach will erase whitespace inside tags as well.

Comment: Also, please note that newlines are exactly the same as spaces to an HTML renderer unless you declare otherwise in CSS. Instead of using `nl2br` (like I guess you do), use CSS to specify newlines should be preserved inside the tags where you want to keep it.

Comment: If you want to prevent _all_ whitespace between two elements, the usual solution is to float the elements instead. Also, there's a tag in Smarty to consume / not consume whitespace.

Comment: @Jacob, I found that topic and couldn't adapt the logic to what I want to do.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what end up on the screen after processing. It's a matter of having the right formating for another later treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will suffice ?

```
<?php
$html=<<<SOMECONT
<p>some text</p>





<p>some other random
text with \n at fixed width
and thats great</p>
SOMECONT;

$narr=array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL,$html),'strlen');
echo implode('',$narr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
<p>some text</p><p>some other randomtext with 
 at fixed widthand thats great</p>
```

**EDIT : ALTERNATIVE**

Might be more "dirty" but works. Afterall, removing all \n between htmltags can sometimes be as simple as removing empty lines from an exploded string of the original file.

```
  $split = explode(PHP_EOL,$data);
  $data= "";
  for($i = 0; $i < count($split); $i++){
    $line = $split[$i];
    else if(strlen($line) > 0) $data .= $split[$i]."\n"; // filter
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that remove line breaks also between html tags ?

Comment: the strlen here evaluate if the length is > 0 to remove each "empty lines" right ? It should work but somehow it's not. But I created a dirty way to do the same thing with a explode on PHP_EOL and then filter with the strlen().

Thanks

Comment: @Lego, Glad you got it working. You can edit this answer like how you did , so others can get benefitted!.

Comment: Both these examples still remove line breaks within tags.