# PHP: file_get_contents and cURL gives a 404 because of a "myterious" line break

Tags: php, phpquery

I am using [PhpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to get all links with an specific class and after that I want to get the html source of each link to mess a little bit.

But the first thing is that I am getting the links from a site I am doing a research about. I do not have any administrator rights of the site I am using.

So, in order to do all I my research in my localhost environment, I accomplished to change all links from something like this:

```
<a class="linkHtml" href="search?q=HUGE_QUERY_HERE">link</a>
```

to:

```
<a class="linkHtml" href="http://www.domain.com/search?q=HUGE_QUERY_HERE">link</a>
```

using this PHP code here:

```
foreach (pq('.linkHtml') as $link) {                
    $id = pq($link)->parent()->prev()->text();              
    $search = 'search?q=';
    $replace = 'http://www.domain.com/busca/search?q=';
    $subject = pq($link)->attr('href'); 
    $pageUrl =str_replace($search,$replace,$subject);               

    pq($link)->attr('href',$pageUrl);                   

   /* more code here */
}
```

The problem is that somehow the first `?` is breaking the string. I cant even reproduce that same error in text, I'll have to upload pictures of it.

Considering the code above, if I do a `var_dump($pageUrl)` and try to connect it will result on this:

[image]

You can see that it looks like it has a line break after the `search?`, even tough it clearly doesn't have. I already tried to remove all line breaks based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258543/remove-all-the-line-breaks-from-the-html-source) answers and others and got no luck. And it tries to connect as if the url ended on the question mark.

If I change the code to:

```
$pageUrl =str_replace("search?q=", "searchq=", $pageUrl);       
var_dump($pageUrl);
```

will result in this:
[image]

As you can see, it will try to connect to correctly, but obviously `searchq=` is wrong.

What am I missing? Where that line break come from?
I said I can not reproduce it in text because if I copy it, it will look normal, as there is nothing there and the site will work normally.

**EDIT:** 
Also tried this with no luck.

```
$pageUrl = urlencode($pageUrl);
$pageUrl = str_replace("%2f","/",$pageUrl); 
$pageUrl = str_replace("%3A",":",$pageUrl); 
$content = file_get_contents($pageUrl);
```

After changing the strings to single quotes, a `var_dump` of each of them result on this:

[image]

*Apologies for using all those images, but I don't know a better way to reproduce the exact same problem. Also sorry for always hiding the site domain making the images dirty, but I have to.*

Comment: try using the string with one quote ' instead of "

Comment: First thing I will do is to echo the 3 strings: 1 original string, 2 replace string , 3 the replaced string

Comment: I will try. It was a long time since I last used php, so I've got used to double quote as in other languages.

Comment: Its ok to use these double quotes I just assumed something wrong,

Comment: I think you have some breaking lines chars which are not visible in html, please see my answer below I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: You could just concatenate `http://domaine.com` with `search?q` instead of using str_replace !

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some breacking lines chars which breakes your url,
try to do this:

```
$findStringsArr = array("\0","\n","\r","search?q=");
$replaceStringsWithArr = array("","","","http://www.domain.com/busca/search?q=");
$subject = pq($link)->attr('href'); 
$pageUrl = str_replace($findStringsArr,$replaceStringsWithArr,$subject);
```

Comment: from the pictures you shared it visible to see that there are some breaking lines chars which are not visible in html

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work, just tried now. Seriously, it is driving me crazy.

Comment: do it before you do the urlencode, also echo the result string in echo '<pre>'.var_dump($pageUrl,true).'</pre>';

Comment: It prints the string normally, without that strange line break.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70310/discussion-between-talsibony-and-patrick-bard).

Comment: If I copy any link, that or the one including the "line break" and paste on the browser it always works, because there isn't a line break. But with the `<pre>` tag (which I forgot), it displays the string as it should be.